# Converting a multiband raster to a single band raster wipes off its values

Tags: raster, gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, multi-band

I have a multi-band raster and I am using

```
gdal_translate -b 1 -scale 30 30 landscape.lcp band_1.tif
```

to get a single band in tif format. Now if I check values of band 1 in landscape.lcp, those lie between 0 -270. But if I check values in band1.tif, the values lie between -32768- 32767. Any pointer how to keep the original values in the band_1.tif file.

Comment: What is your aim with using -scale 30 30?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you don't want to rescale the input pixel values (`-scale`) but set the target resolution (`-tr`), so try with:

```
gdal_translate -b 1 -tr 30 30 landscape.lcp band_1.tif
```